# An equivalent norm in a subspace of $H^2 (\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, equivalent-metrics

The following questions concerns a problem I am treating in my Masters dissertation.

Let $\Omega $ be an open, bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then the norm

$$
\Vert u\Vert^2 = \Vert u\Vert_2^2 + \Vert\nabla u\Vert_2^2 + \Vert\Delta u\Vert_2^2 
$$

equivalent to the usual norm in $H^2 (\Omega)$. Indeed, I know from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124493/doubt-on-norm-of-the-sobolev-space-h2-mathbbr3) that $(\Vert u\Vert_2^2 + \Vert\Delta u\Vert_2^2)^{1/2}$ is equivalent to the norm in $H^2(\Omega)$. From this follows that for some $c > 0$

\begin{align*}
c \Vert u\Vert_{H^2}^2 & \leq \Vert u \Vert_2^2 + \Vert\Delta u\Vert_2^2 \\
& \leq \Vert u\Vert_2^2 + \Vert\nabla u\Vert_2^2 + \Vert\Delta u\Vert_2^2 \\
& \leq \Vert u\Vert_{H^2}^2
\end{align*}

Now, let 
$$
V = \left\{u \in H^2(\Omega) \ : \ \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega\right\}
$$
and 
$$
\tilde V = \left\{ u \in V \ : \ \int_\Omega u \ dx = 0 \right\}.
$$
How can I show that
$$
\Vert u\Vert = \Vert\nabla u\Vert_2 + \Vert\Delta u\Vert_2
$$
is an equivalent norm on $\tilde V$? Does it follow from the Poincaré-Wirtinger inequality?

Comment: The hint for your actual question is Poincaré's inequality. But you have to be careful - the linked question treats the case of Sobolev spaces on $\mathbb{R}^d$, for the version on bounded domains you need some boundary regularity. Without it, this equivalence of norms can fail (Mazya's book on Sobolev spaces contains some cautionary examples).

Comment: @MaoWao By boundary regularity you mean that the boundary must be regular or that the function must have some regularity on the boundary? In my case I am dealing with an smooth, bounded open set.

Comment: I meant regularity of the boundary. If it is smooth, you are fine.

Comment: I still can't write the argument, could you help me @MaoWao?

Comment: $c\|u\|_{H^2}^2 \leq \|u-0\|_2^2+\|\Delta u\|_2^2 \leq C(\|\nabla u\|_2^2 + \|\Delta u\|^2_2) \leq C \|u\|_{H^2}^2$ for all $u \in \tilde V$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already noted, $(\|u\|_2+\|\Delta u\|_2)^{1/2}$ is an equivalent norm on $H^2$, hence there is a constant $c>0$ such that
$$c\|u\|_{H^2}^2 \leq \|u\|_2^2+\|\Delta u\|_2^2, \quad \forall u \in H^2.$$
This is also true for $u \in \tilde V \subset H^2$. Since the elements in $\tilde V$ have zero mean, we can make use of the following Poincare inequality,
$$\|u\|_2^2 \leq C_P\|\nabla u\|^2,  \quad \forall u \in \tilde V. $$

Putting these two inequalities together, we have for all $u \in \tilde V$,

$$c\|u\|_{H^2}^2 \leq \|u\|_2^2+\|\Delta u\|_2^2 \leq C_P\|\nabla u\|_2^2 + \|\Delta u\|^2_2 \leq C (\|\nabla u\|_2^2 + \|\Delta u\|^2_2) \leq C \|u\|_{H^2}^2,$$

where $C:=\max\{1,C_P\}$. Hence, $(\|\nabla u\|_2^2 + \|\Delta u\|_2^2)^{1/2}$ is an equivalent norm on $\tilde V$.